# How to put x-axis labels in Vega using "datum"?

Tags: vega

In Vega, I want to put in the x-axis labels an expression with the data from the "reference" column. I have only been able to put a fixed label for all the values (commented line 67), but when I try to put the expression "datum.reference" in the text, I can't do it (line 68). Could you help me? Thank you very much in advance

The code is the following:

````
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",

  "width": 400,  
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,   
  "autosize": "pad",  

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28, "reference": "ref1"},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55, "reference": "ref2"},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43, "reference": "ref3"},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91, "reference": "ref1"},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81, "reference": "ref4"},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53, "reference": "ref5"},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19, "reference": "ref6"},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87, "reference": "ref7"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

"axes": [
  {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "scale": "xscale",
    "title": "X-Axis",
    "encode": {
      "ticks": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "steelblue"}
        }
      },
      "labels": {
        "interactive": true,
        "update": {
          //"text": {"value": "x_label"},       // Line 67: This is fine
          "text": {"expr": "datum.reference"},  // Line 68: Here, I have the problem
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "angle": {"value": 50},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
          "align": {"value": "left"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "dx": {"value": 3}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "update": {
          "fontSize": {"value": 16}
        }
      },
      "domain": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#333"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5}
        }
      }
    }


  },

    { "orient": "left", 
    "scale": "yscale",
    "title": "Y-Axis", 
    "tickCount": 4,"offset": 6 }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "isNaN(tooltip.amount)", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```
````

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, "datum" in Vega *axis* does not refer to any item in the dataset "table". Instead, Vega *axis* uses an internally generated dataset based on the *scale* defined for that axis.

See [Vega documentation for "axis"](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/axes/). The documentation also states that (without giving an example):

> Custom text can be defined using the "text" property for labels. For example, one could define an ordinal scale that serves as a lookup table from axis values to axis label text.

Here is an example of how to use a lookup dataset and *scale* for this purpose. Note that all values of "category" must be unique and all values for "reference" must be unique.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",

  "width": 400,  
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,   
  "autosize": "pad",  

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "data_lookup",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "reference": "ref1"},
        {"category": "B", "reference": "ref2"},
        {"category": "C", "reference": "ref3"},
        {"category": "D", "reference": "ref10"},
        {"category": "E", "reference": "ref4"},
        {"category": "F", "reference": "ref5"},
        {"category": "G", "reference": "ref6"},
        {"category": "H", "reference": "ref7"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "scale_lookup",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_lookup", "field": "category"},
      "range": {"data": "data_lookup", "field": "reference"}
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

"axes": [
  {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "scale": "xscale",
    "title": "X-Axis",
    "encode": {
      "ticks": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "steelblue"}
        }
      },
      "labels": {
        "interactive": true,
        "update": {

         "text": {"signal": "scale('scale_lookup', datum.value)"},

          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "angle": {"value": 50},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
          "align": {"value": "left"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "dx": {"value": 3}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "update": {
          "fontSize": {"value": 16}
        }
      },
      "domain": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#333"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5}
        }
      }
    }


  },

    { "orient": "left", 
    "scale": "yscale",
    "title": "Y-Axis", 
    "tickCount": 4,"offset": 6 }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "isNaN(tooltip.amount)", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[View in Vega online editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aACwAGNTPg0yWNACYNMnEgUKa4smgEykDTGwg0AXnDQgTC6SAVJMKVABtUHEkBDd0fyYAGzcZYiRohjgINGCQKD9yNgAnAE93AEFvMLYGcUwDAA4AXylQTMxs-PcAIRKEMorrATqGrLJcgvQAYQ6uytQVAGY+jIGh9wARcfLJgE4ARjnG5uGQAFFV7tQq7fr5psGW9AAxY8mBWYvd6-2AcQe0TfWdhZuQAAJL6nADsNQAunNQuF3L5-AB9aJsNgAawYOG8CSSKTS-Sui3QxRkOTgADM4KTxFAIiBSWTNiA-gSAe0SeTKXBqbT6fomS9-vsxuyKVSae56dN+fi9stvPTOdyJeTNmppZdZegjiLFeL0PSVOrXoSQPcdWKeeSBEbBe5PuauXq6eSAGw2ln7YEOpX68mgplQiEyJxkULRVJBEJhWkONjRTA0THxRLJNDAOogCR4kBwUgVCPOqCYVCdBgQOBsUg5bwY+G0+EMBDq3NczAF0lFktlctlSoyWtZdzpgOQ4OZWIR9Iw2nQRJwJEo9FJkCYPI4Wm5cxh7wKNjICxpnx+AJHxHItEY7xkmhwaJedDGloZnJISwRUDwk+fhcX5fX2-3s6oqOm4NTQtG7gAB6zrE3iruu7hMK+XgyLu+6SKgH7Hu4USwTI-53u4j4FM+r5kLS8hKDA3ieFuVioGolBqDYdJdPemA5Mk4GwugeQwXEPh7kgB6YaeJ64QJBGAaUaz8iA4g0HqHHJCSZG0touiVKOIBIJBuKRpmOQ3icIBMGw2B7t4-FQdZMgJpgsHoAAGgAtIUkE0KkMiOmwCjviuimohGoADk0h4QBxaL+diqboBFcC3jEqZgRm0RIEwt7BSAFhNC+RY0KQaDKXA-Y4HWh5NJBkygCG25xeOcAABQAOT8T+S7NVIAAEDYIJQMVwAAlHJ17RNEh4De48WJTiclkY5oCTagAhqBmZISJgADKLjRSmESbCoGaJDoGGLXt7ixGSWkyEh5bRBYu2zegCCKAosEZgokETedqCzBmMCVpSh6jeNolLSA16kkwRlQKiTJgXZdALSAoX+etFTba431PZsLopahQkiSFZWDqJEU5FF2OxSAADE0z03J5NRQA6ooyhgz9myUL0KVzLkxmTCAl19iA1m8bZAUObSACabkeV5AWwyMEyqDIbBkmS5aTHjQYgMgORBdm8GWkWV4U02omfjh6Xvd51K+f5rZA6JX1kw1Nnu-hN6EQ+toZpR7M1e76DQZ7pnId8GbDEHc7uHxYdSe4MndFHfJu7H4th0tq0ZqjwM0GNVMzk0M3Jf9gPVqJINF8qXi8xcxs4XAVXeD5fmHk7legMdoY1w+ndybdt4PX3pnmQ4TZrQXoNnU9tP01KCMoyTYUu+FwcgKHsfBidiQ4Si8aJpQxHeEh4j3oxvQyNHosb-H2+i7voMrgfCY4JQyci+rmtwJMLn6BmSq1VH6hj3pEV+R9P4jWngAeRMFAOgwx0hNAiu4TyAA5JA6DGqxkPu-T+w1kxPVWhcJa2woRgShEAA)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem in a very simple way. Just creating a transform that concatenates the two fields and then using that new column to represent the data. Anyway thank you very much for the other solution that I find very interesting and useful.

Here I provide the code of what I wanted to achieve

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",

  "width": 400,  
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,   
  "autosize": "pad",  

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28, "reference": "ref1"},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55, "reference": "ref2"},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43, "reference": "ref3"},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91, "reference": "ref1"},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81, "reference": "ref4"},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53, "reference": "ref5"},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19, "reference": "ref6"},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87, "reference": "ref7"}
      ],

      "transform":[
      {"type": "formula",
      "expr": "datum.category + ' (' + datum.reference + ')' ",
      "as": "category(ref)"}
    ]
    },

    
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category(ref)"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

"axes": [
  {
    "orient": "bottom",
    "scale": "xscale",
    "title": "X-Axis",
    "encode": {
      "ticks": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "steelblue"}
        }
      },
      "labels": {
        "interactive": true,
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
           "angle": {"value": 50},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
          "align": {"value": "left"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "dx": {"value": 3}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "update": {
          "fontSize": {"value": 16}
        }
      },
      "domain": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#333"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1.5}
        }
      }
    }


  },

    { "orient": "left", 
    "scale": "yscale",
    "title": "Y-Axis", 
    "tickCount": 4,"offset": 6 }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category(ref)"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "isNaN(tooltip.amount)", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```